# Transformation logic in hive / spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql, informatica

How can we write a **`Hive query`** in **`select`** statement for the logic below ?

> - If a column value is null then it should return ' '
> - If trim(column) is null then it should return ' '
> - Else it should populate the value of that column.

I guess this can be implemented using case when approach. 
How to implement in a **`Hive query`**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select coalesce(trim(column), '')
```

Note that `trim()` doesn't take a second argument in Hive.  Also, `trim()` doesn't return `NULL` unless the argument is `NULL`; it returns an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert Linoff.Actually I wanted to transformation the below logic : Decode(true,isnull(column),' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(column))=",' ',column)